# Publish pyflakes and sloccount Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline, pyflakes

Is it possible to publish pyflakes stats and slocount using Jenkinsfile.
I suceeded publishing a junit file but do not know how two proceed wuth this two technos above

I used step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: 'xunit.xml'])

Do pyflakes and slocount have ab equivalent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Those plugins are not compatible yet
Find the link where the compatible plugins are https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md